# In react js can we create an array even if the page rerender the content or array should be there?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Suppose if i want to push elements in an array in React Js where the page itself rerender, Is there any way we can keep adding the elements and keep the content as it is ?

```
const getindexlastpage = (index) => {
  const item = [];
  item.push(index);
  return console.log(item);
};

export default getindexlastpage;
```

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: I don't completely understand the question. If we're talking an array that is not part of the state of a component you can push elements into it and nothing is re-renderd. Can you clarify what the problem is exactly?

Comment: adding element to the above array by push overide the old content.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? Do you want to persist data across re-renders but updating that data itself shouldn't trigger a re-render?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think the problem is that you're creating the `item` array anew each time you call `getindexlastpage`.

If you want to append to the `item` array without recreating it you can simply move the array definition outside the function.

For example:

```
const item = [];

const getindexlastpage = (index) => {
  item.push(index);
  // Do other stuff...
};

export default getindexlastpage;
```